# background-attachment:fixed and background-size: cover makes images dissapear in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, background-attachment

I think this is a common issue with Chrome but I could not find a workaround.

[See my code here (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/4Rwze/)

The first two background images are shown but the background images of #sec3 and #sec4 don't appear in Chrome on Mac OS. Firefox and Safari are working just fine...

When I change the height of the sections to a bit less, the third image is displayed...:

```
.main_section {
     height: 700px;
}
```

Do you know what is causing this? Does it also happen on Windows or Linux? Do you know a fix to this or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,

Nick =)

Comment: Same in Chrome on Windows: last two images are missing. If I switch `background-attachment` back to `scroll` they become visible. Looks like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: I have tested it in an older version of Chrome for Mac (Version 25) and it worked just fine. So it seems to be a bug in the latest version and the latest beta/dev version (28.0.1500.71,29.0.1547.22 beta, Version 30.0.1568.2 dev)

Comment: You should report it then.

Comment: we are facing the same problem, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your current code in the jsfiddle:

HTML:

```
<section class="main_section" id="sec1" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.2">
    <article class="section_details">
        <h1>Start</h1>
    </article>
</section>

<section class="main_section" id="sec2" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.2">
    <article class="section_details">
        <h1>Überschrift</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut ante eu massa consectetur consequat. Nullam interdum justo vitae mi tristique interdum.
            Mauris arcu metus, gravida sed malesuada in, euismod in libero. Nulla euismod ultrices pulvinar. In at gravida nulla. Suspendisse at neque ut neque convallis
            hendrerit. Maecenas mollis placerat commodo. Maecenas ornare magna vitae nulla mollis accumsan. Nullam nec congue lorem. In eleifend, elit porttitor cursus hendrerit,
            turpis justo tincidunt ante, sed imperdiet velit arcu vitae ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
            Mauris sed turpis felis. Donec sit amet aliquam quam. Duis at orci aliquam metus bibendum egestas nec sit amet sem. Aliquam eget diam nulla, eget porttitor ligula.
            Sed at velit vel tellus consequat gravida sit amet sit amet nunc. Nam convallis interdum arcu ut interdum. Curabitur vitae eros felis.</p>
    </article>

</section>

<section class="main_section" id="sec3" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.2">
    <article class="section_details">
        <h1>Überschrift</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut ante eu massa consectetur consequat. Nullam interdum justo vitae mi tristique interdum.
            Mauris arcu metus, gravida sed malesuada in, euismod in libero. Nulla euismod ultrices pulvinar. In at gravida nulla. Suspendisse at neque ut neque convallis
            hendrerit. Maecenas mollis placerat commodo. Maecenas ornare magna vitae nulla mollis accumsan. Nullam nec congue lorem. In eleifend, elit porttitor cursus hendrerit,
            turpis justo tincidunt ante, sed imperdiet velit arcu vitae ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
            Mauris sed turpis felis. Donec sit amet aliquam quam. Duis at orci aliquam metus bibendum egestas nec sit amet sem. Aliquam eget diam nulla, eget porttitor ligula.
            Sed at velit vel tellus consequat gravida sit amet sit amet nunc. Nam convallis interdum arcu ut interdum. Curabitur vitae eros felis.</p>
    </article>
</section>

<section class="main_section" id="sec4" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.2">
    <article class="section_details">
        <h1>Überschrift</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut ante eu massa consectetur consequat. Nullam interdum justo vitae mi tristique interdum.
            Mauris arcu metus, gravida sed malesuada in, euismod in libero. Nulla euismod ultrices pulvinar. In at gravida nulla. Suspendisse at neque ut neque convallis
            hendrerit. Maecenas mollis placerat commodo. Maecenas ornare magna vitae nulla mollis accumsan. Nullam nec congue lorem. In eleifend, elit porttitor cursus hendrerit,
            turpis justo tincidunt ante, sed imperdiet velit arcu vitae ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
            Mauris sed turpis felis. Donec sit amet aliquam quam. Duis at orci aliquam metus bibendum egestas nec sit amet sem. Aliquam eget diam nulla, eget porttitor ligula.
            Sed at velit vel tellus consequat gravida sit amet sit amet nunc. Nam convallis interdum arcu ut interdum. Curabitur vitae eros felis.</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.main_section {
    height: 1000px;
}

#sec1 {
    background: url("http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3718/9321223260_700efbede4_b.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#sec2 {
    background: url("http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7422/9320632979_1cc63b1320_b.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#sec3 {
    background: url("http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2863/9322473736_76944327d5_b.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#sec4 {
    background: url("http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3719/9319325635_14e101bbdb_b.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.section_details {
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

This appears to be a bug in Google Chrome.
This does happen on Linux in the current version of Chrome.

You can apply a property of

```
.section_details {margin: 1px;}
```

in order to work around the display issue.  As I am not a Chromium developer, I cannot tell you what goes on behind the scenes that this "fixes" it, but good luck! :)  Hopefully this will get resolved soon.

If you do not want the margin to actually show, you may be able to add

```
.section_details {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.01);
    transform: scale(1.01);
}
```

as well.

edit: See it in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjordanca/4Rwze/1/